# Get available apartments

Tags: php, mysql

With this query i will find all apartments that are available.
All the available apartments have no booking id.

What i want: When it has a booking id and the status is cancelled I also want the apartment to  show up, but i don't know how to…

```
  SELECT a.id, a.num_persons, a.rating, a.lat, a.lng, a.street, a.number
      ,c.title, c.introduction, c.text, c.area, c.long_term_rental, c.beds
      , c.features ,c.services_and_equipment, c.terms_and_conditions
      , m.url
    FROM appartments AS a
    INNER JOIN appartments_content AS c on c.parent_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN meta AS m on m.id = c.meta_id
    LEFT JOIN appartments_bookings AS b 
           ON (b.appartment_id = a.id 
          AND NOT ((? > b.departure) OR (? < b.arrival)))    
         --    this ? = arrival     that ? = departure
    WHERE b.id IS NULL 
      AND c.language = ? 
      AND a.hidden = ? 
      AND a.publish_on <= ? 
      AND a.city_id = ? 
      AND a.num_persons >= ? 

    ORDER BY a.num_persons ASC, a.publish_on DESC
    LIMIT ? OFFSET ?'
```

I added this:

```
AND b.status != ? OR NOT ((? >= b.departure) OR (? < b.arrival))) WHERE b.order_id IS NULL
```

But this doesn't work, i get nog results.

Comment: Maybe you should include table definitions of appartments, appartments_content and appartments_bookings in your question.

Comment: give the data structure, i forgot my crystal globe at home today:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know mySQL syntax but change your WHERE to clause to something like...

WHERE (b.id IS NULL OR (b.id IS NOT NULL AND b.status = 'cancelled'))
  AND c.language = etc etc